# How to render the checked or unchecked checkbox based on some boolean value from an api in react?

Tags: html, reactjs, jsx

I am trying to render checked or unchecked checkbox based on some boolean value from an api. How do i do that in react jsx?

Comment: try creating a variable in a state which will store boolean values and bind a event handler to that checkbox when it will be clicked event handler will get triggered and will update the state.

Comment: can you give more information please? like a CodeSanbox or something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm starting with an example:

```
API:
{
  some_thing : true
}
```

React:

```
<input type="checkbox" defaultChecked={some_thing} />
```

Result :
you have checked checkbox

Comment: It must be `<input type="checkbox" defaultChecked={some_thing} /> `. After doing that it worked for me. Thanks for the insight.